# Using perl to parse Photobucket RSS feed?

Tags: perl, rss

Trying to read and parse the RSS feed from Photobucket, and I'm having a hard time getting at sub elements of the  element. Here's the sample RSS XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
        <title>BlahBlah&apos;s Photobucket websitePic album media</title>
        <description>A feed of BlahBlah&apos;s images and videos for this album</description>
        <pubDate>Sun, 7 Aug 2011 20:11:31 MDT</pubDate>
        <link>http://s1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/?sort=ascending</link>

        <lastBuildDate>Mon, 13 Feb 2012 21:04:43 MST</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>Photobucket feed generator</generator>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <ttl>60</ttl>
        <item>
            <title>F1 sidecar</title>

            <link>http://s1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/?action=view&amp;current=IMG_0673.jpg&amp;sort=ascending</link>
            <dc:creator>BlahBlah</dc:creator>
            <description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://s1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/&quot;&gt;BlahBlah&lt;/a&gt; posted a photo&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://s1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/?action=view&amp;current=IMG_0673.jpg&amp;sort=ascending&quot; title=&quot;IMG_0673.jpg&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/th_IMG_0673.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;IMG_0673.jpg&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br&gt;F1 sidecar - IMG_0673.jpg&lt;/p&gt;</description>

            <guid>http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/IMG_0673.jpg</guid>
            <enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/IMG_0673.jpg" />
            <media:content medium="image" type="image/jpeg" url="http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/IMG_0673.jpg">
                <media:title>F1 car</media:title>
                <media:description />
                <media:thumbnail url="http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/th_IMG_0673.jpg" />
            </media:content>
            <pubDate>Sun, 7 Aug 2011 20:11:31 MDT</pubDate>

        </item>
```

I want to get at the  element to grab it's value. Here's my code, which doesn't work...

```
use strict;
use CGI;
use XML::RSS;
use LWP::Simple;

my $test = CGI->new;
my $url = "http://feed1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/feed.rss";

my $rss = XML::RSS->new();
my $data = get( $url );
$rss->parse( $data );

$rss->add_module(prefix=>'media', uri=>'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

print $test->header("text/html");

my $channel = $rss->{channel};

foreach my $item ( @{ $rss->{items} } )
{
    my $link  = $item->{link};
    my $title = $item->{title};
    my $thumb = '';

    foreach my $b ( { $item->{'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'}->{'content'} })
    {
        print "here\n";
        if( $b->{'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'}->{'thumbnail'}->{'url'} )
        {
            $thumb = $thumb . ' ' . $b->{'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'}->{'thumbnail'}->{'url'};
        }
    }

    print $title, "\n", $link, "\nthumb=", $thumb, "\n\n\n";
}

print $test->end_html;
```

It will loop through all the channel item's, and will find the  element, but I can't seem to get the child elements. I think my syntax is close. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` thing from your example is parsed into this structure:

```
items => [
  {
    dc => {
      creator => "BlahBlah"
    },
    description => "<p><a href=\"http://s1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/\">BlahBlah</a> posted a photo</a></p><p><a href=\"http://s1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/?action=view&current=IMG_0673.jpg&sort=ascending\" title=\"IMG_0673.jpg\"><img src=\"http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/th_IMG_0673.jpg\" alt=\"IMG_0673.jpg\" /></a><br>F1 sidecar - IMG_0673.jpg</p>",
    enclosure => {
      type => "image/jpeg",
      url => "http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/IMG_0673.jpg"
    },
    guid => "http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/IMG_0673.jpg",
    "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" => {
      creator => "BlahBlah"
    },
    "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" => {
      content => "\n                ...",
      title => "F1 car"
    },
    isPermaLink => "",
    item => "\n            \n\n ...",
    link => "http://s1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/?action=view&current=IMG_0673.jpg&sort=ascending",
    pubDate => "Sun, 7 Aug 2011 20:11:31 MDT",
    title => "F1 sidecar"
  }
],
```

For instance I don't see any `"thumbnail"` key under `"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"`. It is good idea to dump your data to see how exactly they look like. See modules like [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDump) for that.

Comment: This is the element I want, and I need the 'url' attribute of the element:    <media:thumbnail url="http://i1100.photobucket.com/albums/g409/BlahBlah/websitePic/th_IMG_0673.jpg" />                                       But thanks, I'll try data dump.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typo on this line:

```
foreach my $b ( { $item->{'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'}->{'content'} })
```

I think you're missing an "@" in front of the first "{" there.

Comment: If I do, then I get the following error    Can't use string ("

              "...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Comment: I'm not sure then. I don't think I've ever had the "pleasure" of dealing with the namespace syntax used by XML::RSS. It does mean, though, that `$item->{'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'}->{'content'}` is not something you can iterator over. You need to find a different way. I'd suggest inserting "use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($item);" just above your foreach to tell you what is actually in there. It might also be that not every post has a media:content tag, in which case you need to detect that first.